# any idea what video encoding technology youtube is using?

Tags: php, encoding, ffmpeg

i was wondering if anyone knew what video/audio encoding technology youtube is using. i heard they started with ffmpeg but am unsure

Answer (score 1):

They use either H.263, H.264 (MPEG-4) or VP8 to encode video.

If I'm not mistaken they are currently porting everything over to [VP8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8), which they acquired from On2 and has been released as Open Source (and should be the code used in [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) as well).

You could also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtube#Video_technology for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just like everything inside of Google's properties there's a chance it's some kind of homebrew solution that's over-optimized to the maximum. So while basically it's a possibility they were used ffmepeg at the start it's impossible they don't rewrite it from time to time.